# What am I missing in this python login function?

Tags: python

I am trying to write a login function using python. However, I can't seem to write the code for checking the username and password against the ones stored in a file. The specific error is NameError: name 'adusername' is not defined. How do I fix this?

```
def adminlogindetails():
    adusername = input("Admin Username: ")
    adpassword = input("Admin Password: ")
    adfile = open("adlogindetails.txt", "a")
    adfile.write(adusername)
    adfile.write(",")
    adfile.write(adpassword)
    adfile.write("\n")
    adfile.close()

def adminverification():
    adun = input("Enter your username:")
    adpw = input("Enter your password:")
    adinfo = open("adlogindetails.txt", "r")
    for line in adinfo:
        adun, adpw = line.split(",")
        if adun == adusername and adpw == adpassword:
            print("Login successful!")
            adminoptions()
        else:
            print("Incorrect username/password")
            roleselection()

adminverification()
```

Comment: When you call `adminverification`, you don't first declare `adusername` or `adpassword`.

Comment: Also you never call `adminlogindetails`

Comment: change the two first line in ```adminverification``` to ```adusername = input("Enter your username:")
    adpassword = input("Enter your password:")```

Comment: You seem to be confused about the scope of variables. A variable defined inside a `def` is not visible outside it. Once you learn how this works, the fix should be obvious and trivial; define the variable you are trying to use.

Comment: I see 2 errors: adun, adpw = line.split(",") and also the for loop will take decision on first iteration

Comment: You want to declare a `class Admin`, then a) make `username` and `password` class members b) rename `adminlogindetails()` to `__init__()` c) assign to `self.username`, `self.password` in `__init__()`, then you can access them in `verification`. And no need for name prefix of `admin` or `ad` on all your functions and variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not declared `adusername` and `adpassword` in `adminverification()`. So, it is causing the error. If you want to use the variables from `adminlogindetails()`, change the variables name since you have stored the details in `adlogindetails.txt`.

The below code should be changed as `line` variable contains the already stored username and password:

```
adun, adpw = line.split(",")
```

Change above piece of code to the shown below:

```
adusername, adpassword = line.split(",")
```

you can use this:

```py
def adminlogindetails():
    adusername = input("Admin Username: ")
    adpassword = input("Admin Password: ")
    adfile = open("adlogindetails.txt", "a")
    adfile.writelines(adusername + ',' + adpassword )
    adfile.close()

def adminverification():
    adun = input("Enter your username:").strip()
    adpw = input("Enter your password:").strip()
    with open("adlogindetails.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        i = 0
        for line in lines:
            adusername, adpassword= line.split(",")
            adusername = str(adusername).strip()
            adpassword = str(adpassword).strip()
            if (adun == adusername) and (adpw == adpassword):
                print("Login successful!()")
                adminoptions()
                break
            else:
                i += 1
                if i >= len(lines): #If no any match upto last line, this will be true
                    print("Incorrect username/password")
                    roleselection()
                    break
    
adminverification()
```

Comment: thanks for all the help, I have fixed it accordingly. But now when I enter the correct name and password both results for meeting the criteria (adminoptions()) and not meeting the criteria appears (roleselection()). how do I fix this?

Comment: Try printing `adusername` and `adpassword` before printing `login successful`. Also print `adusername` and `adpassword` before printing `Incorrect username/password`. Can you elaborate more what problem are you facing now by updating your main question?

Comment: when i input a correct username and password, the result is "Login successful!" followed by the adminoptions() result and right underneath it "Incorrect username/password" and the roleselection() result. basically both result for true and false appear

Comment: Your code has some logic problem. It will only check the first line of file and decide whether it is matching or not.

Comment: in my file, i have 2 lines for 2 usernames and passwords. the break solves the issue when I type the first username and password. but if I type the one in the 2nd line, it returns the false result

Comment: Can you check it now?

Comment: both usernames return the false value

Comment: What it means by false values? is print login successful shown? or what?

Comment: no issue for 1st username but 2nd returns Incorrect username/password

Comment: @Crowno Ok updated it once again. It will fix everything

Comment: lifesaver, can you explain what the i = 0 and i+=1 does?

Comment: `i` is just a variable which will keep on increasing in `else` part (If user type variable did not match with stored variable). If `i` becomes equal to the length of the initial list, it will mean that `for loop` is executed till last and still usernames and password did not match with any. So it will print `unsuccessful login`.

Comment: You can use `print()` to check what each variable is storing. This logic of using `i` is generally useful in login where user type variable has to be checked upto last else print `unsuccessful`

Comment: so based on my understanding, i is the number of lines in the file? so if I is more than the number of lines in the file means all lines have been checked and no match so result in Incorrect username/password?

Comment: @Crowno you are right. Initial value of `i` is 0 but it will increase as for loop iterates. Its max value will be the total line of the txt file

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are not calling `adminlogindetails()`.

Also `adusername` is a local variable and you should either make it global using `global adusername` in the `adminlogindetails` function or declare it outside of the functions in the global scope.

See this - https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_scope.asp

Answer (score 0):

This line is your problem:

```
adun, adpw = line.split(",")
```

"adun" and "adpw" are your inputs and you are overwriting them. Replace with this and it will be ok:

```
adusername, adpassword = line.replace("\n", "").split(",")
```

Note: "\n" needs to be removed for your comparison to be ok.